# SQL Do we need to always join 2 tables when a table has an FK?

Tags: sql, select, inner-join

I don't know how legit this question is, I have been thinking this for a while.
Say I have 2 tables, Table A and Table B.
In table A we have

```
TableA
--------
ID  int not null PK
ANOTHER_COLOLUMN String null,
....
TABLE_B_ID (FK, int, not null)
```

and Table B

```
TableB
-------
ID int not null PK,
....
....
```

My question is, do we always need to have

```
select * from TableA inner join TableB on TableA.id = TableB.id
```

if I am just using TableA (and I am not touching tableB at all)?

Comment: No need to join to TableB if you don't need any information from TableB.

Comment: You can try **select * from TableA**

Answer (score 0):

Your query

```
select * from TableA inner join TableB on TableA.id = TableB.id
```

will return only those records from table A that have related records in table B.

In your case you need to use following queue:

```
select * from TableA
```

and no matter if it has foreign key or not.

Answer (score 0):

No. If your are not using data present in TableB, then there is no need to use FK or join.